# How to add different text after echo output using PHP

Tags: php, dom

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();

@$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);

$classname = 'winning-numbers';

$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

 foreach ($nodes as $node) {
echo "<p>","<b>11 AM Draw:","\n",$node->nodeValue,"</b>","</p>";

// I add paragraph and bold tags on the echo output but this site recognize the tags.

}
```

I'm almost done with it.
The problem is I want to output like this

```
 11 AM Draw: 111(just an example value)
 4 PM Draw: 222(just an example value)
 9 PM Draw: 333(just an example value)
```

but I'm getting this

```
11 AM Draw: 2-2-0
11 AM Draw: 7-7-2
11 AM Draw: 1-6-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `str_replace` function to find and replace characters in your string:

```
$time = array('11 AM', '4 PM', '9 PM');
$i = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo "<p><b>".$time[$i]." : ".str_replace("-","",$node->nodeValue)."</b></p>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hello Thabk you for the response but What Im looking for is not only thereplacement of hypens on the nodevalue but also the string "11AM Draw" for example first echo outputs "11AM Draw: 1-1-1" then the next echo outputs "4-PM Draw: 2-2-2"then the last echo outputs "9-PM Draw: 3-3-3"

Comment: Ok, so are you storing the time value for each node inside $node also?

Comment: No I would just like to add string before the nodevalue

Comment: Hello it still print like this one 11 AM Draw : 683

11 AM Draw : 086

11 AM Draw :

Comment: Yes, that is because you have to replace the value of $time with the value inside $node->mytime or whatever you set it as.

Comment: So your updatd answer would really give me what I want.Adding a different text before the nodevalue after echo prints

Comment: Yes, just set $time to be what you want for each $node you echo. Are you not storing the time inside your $node along with the nodeValue?

Comment: how can I add different text wherein I can only had one text on the $time

Comment: How are these times being allocated to each winning number? Are there a set amount of times? say 11 AM, 4 PM and 9 PM, any more? or just those?

Comment: See updated answer: create an array containing your times, and with each loop, increment the index by 1.